# Asking user for an input until valid response is given - Python

Tags: python-3.x

I've seen a few questions like this, but didn't really get my answer - I'm quite new to python and programming as a whole and I've been stuck on this while loop for a while:

```
juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are there?"))
while juveniles < 0: 
    print("Please enter a valid number of juveniles") 
adults = int(input("How many adults are there?"))
```

At the moment, this piece of code only repeats "Please enter a valid number of juveniles" if I type in a number less than 0 (No surprises there), I want it to keep asking the same question until the user gives anything over 0, and once it's done move onto the next variable (adults). How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

You forget to update the value:

```
juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are there?"))
while juveniles < 0: 
    print("Please enter a valid number of juveniles") 
    juveniles = int(input("How many juveniles are there?"))
adults = int(input("How many adults are there?"))
```